# Mainframe Migration to USS/Github

Tags: migration, hex, mainframe

We are trying to migrate Programs (Not Files) from Mainframe to USS, then ultimately to Github.

We have a Program that is having an issue during the migration. These program(s) contains hex character(s) and is being reformatted during the transfer from Mainframe PDS to Unix.  is there a command i can insert so that Unix will not reformat the values during transfer from MF PDS?

Edit:
Program contains EBCDIC characters x'15' (newline) and x'0D' (carriage return) which introduces spaces x'40' to the file as it is transported 
from z/OS to USS. These padded x'40's pushes the rest of characters into the next line.

1. I am using the below command to transfer from Mainframe to Unix.  This command is triggerred inside the Mainframe by a Batch Agent.

```
cp -U -S a=.CPY  -T -O c=IBM-1047  "//'Insert PDS Here'" /data/Github
```

2. The 2 code snippet that is having an issue has a hex value below, Hex values start on 00 - 0F  and 10 - 1F

```
444444444444444444444444444444444444470000000000000000744444444444
0000000000000000000000000000000000000D0123456789ABCDEFDB0000000000

444444444444444444444444444444444444471111111111111111744444444444
0000000000000000000000000000000000000D0123456789ABCDEFDB0000000000
```

3. Unix reformats with a new line when being viewed in iDZ

Reformatted Line

[image: 1]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. I assume you run the `cp` command on z/OS. Please confirm this in the question. What data does the file contain? Is the hex data a hex dump of the binary data? How do you transfer the file to the UNIX system? Did you convert the character encoding? If yes, how? What command/program do you use to display the file on the UNIX system? Or do you use a program on the mainframe to display the file remotely from a UNIX file system? In the latter case, maybe the UNIX file system cannot store the tag information `-O c=IBM-1047`?

Comment: Hi Bodo, i have edited the question with as much information as i can provide based on your questions.  As for the -O c=IBM-1047, since the only program part of the Cobol Codes that has an issue is the Padded x'15' and x'0D', the rest of more than 1000 Cobol codes does not have an issue

Comment: @UnixNoob I put your code snippet into a member of a PDS and used the same command line you showed. The copied file in USS has exactly the same content as the member of a PDS, except for added new line characters at the end of the line (i.e. `x'15'`). I did this test using both an FB and VB data set and both produced the same result, so I did not see any reformatting when copying to a USS file. However, if you use a USS `cat` command to display the content of the file it will split the text at the `x'15'` character that was in your code snippet which is the correct behavior.

Comment: @MilosLalovic - We are viewing directly using iDZ and the line is reformatted.  This reformatting is also apparent when we push the code from USS to GutHub.  Also, when we try to push the codes back to Mainframe, the reformatting remains.

Comment: If there is an issue it is likely in the iDZ code page converter, although I think question marks should appear for non printable characters that are in your code snippet. If uploading to GitHub results in a wrong content, that too would be a code page converter issue.

Comment: @MilosLalovic - appologies, there are actually 2 sets of hex values that are causing issue(s) during transfer, one is for 00-0F and 10-1F.  I have edited my main post

Comment: @MilosLalovic - yes you are correct. we however is running into an issue when we return the USS Code back to MF PDS using the command: SH cp -O u -S d=.CPY -T /data/GithubCMan/App_Src_Copy/CPY/* "//PDS Here'" The new line X'15' is being transferred by USS back to Mainframe. When we try to validate that no changes on the transmission of codes, our validation fails. Our full flow: Transfer MF to USS Push to Git Transfer from USS to MF Validate that no changes on the MF Files.. "Is there a way to turn off that default behavior when we copy from MF to USS or Vice Versa?"

Comment: I am not aware of any option that would preserve `x'15'` or `x'0D'` characters when a text file is copied back to MF. It is not possible to round trip MF to/from USS a text file which contains these two line brake control characters. Even if you do not need to edit/browse these files when in GirHub, you can not use a binary copy (i.e. -B instead of -T) as this will not restore records when you copy them back to MF. The only solution is to write a copy program that preserves `x'15'` and `'x'0D'` if they are in a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days, prior to the 1985 standard, COBOL did not allow hex literals.  Back then, when needed, programmers would enter the hex values directly into the editor.  Some programmers didn't get the memo, and continue to do things this way.  Any supported mainframe COBOL compiler will now allow hex literals in addition to the old way.

I would suggest modifying the offending COBOL program source line to read

```
       05  FILLER PIC X(16) 
           VALUE X'000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F'.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Codes are Productive and due to time constraints, scope and Testing effort, editing the component is not an option for us. right now